# How to interpret char[] in Eclipse MAT?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am digging for memory leak in the heap dump. What does this char tree mean? I can recognize that red_zoomed.png is from the previous activity that was finished. So what about it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

char[33] means character array storing the string resource "res/drawable-xhdpi/red-zoomed.png" (it's 33 characters long as you can see). Although it belongs to previous activity that is finished, the strings (and other types of objects) defined under res/ and  assets/ are packed during compilation, and loaded before the activities, as part of the application context.
They are part of the AssetManager class on top of which the resources is a view.
So therefore they are not "owned' by the activities but by the application context. The activities share the same application context.